# How to pass an interface argument to a variadic function in Golang?

Tags: go

I have a variadic function Result `func Results(messages ...Message)` that accepts an interface `Message`. It works fine if I pass a single message of type Message, but if i pass a slice of message `Result(slice...)`

Here is the error I get:

`prog.go:38: cannot use messages (type []*SampleMessage) as type []Message in argument to Results`

[Sample Code](http://play.golang.org/p/rNYwiZ0BZB)

Comment: `[]*SampleMessage != []Message`; you need to change `messages`'s declaration to: `var messages []Message`

Comment: It works fine if I pass Results(messages[0], messages[1]), so why won't Results([ ]SampleMessage). I guess you might be right though

Answer (score 3):

You need to restructure slightly. The issue is that a `[]*SampleMessage` cannot convert to `[]Message`. The way to handle this though, is to declare the `messages` slice as being of type `[]Message`. Then you can append instances of `SampleMessage` to it without any problems and pass them into your variadic function with the `...` syntax. Here's your example modified to compile; http://play.golang.org/p/cQUIZTz_vo - only change is on the first line of main where I have `var messages []Message`. If you try to do this in the reverse order (like use a []*SampleMessages then do a conversion with `[]Message(messages)` as you pass it) it will fail. So as far as I know, this is the most practical way to solve your problem.